# rspec test doesn't seem to connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I was taking a look at the ol hartl tutorial and even though he goes a little crazy with the testing, I've been able to follow so far until I hit this one test that is a bit confusing to me. I was wondering if one of you more experienced devs can share his logic for this test :

```
  describe "with invalid password" do
    let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

    it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
    specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
  end
```

To me, it looks like he is creating a variable defined with a return value of a user with invalid authentication.

He then takes said variable and says it should not equal itself.

Then he also says that same variable should be false.

For transparency, here is the complete test :

```
describe "return value of authenticate method" do
  before { @user.save }
  let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) }

  describe "with valid password" do
    it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
  end

  describe "with invalid password" do
    let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

    it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
    specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
  end
end
```

Can someone explain where I misunderstood? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's some context missing here. The `it` is being used implicitly, which means RSpec already has a subject in mind. It determines the subject a number of ways, some implicitly (based on class and `describe` block names, among other things), and some explicitly, via the [`subject`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/subject/explicit-subject) keyword. It's likely that there's a `subject` defined outside the `describe` block.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. I added the rest of the test to my post. He does define `found_user` as correct authentication but I dont think `it` is referring to that. I don't know what `it` is supposed to mean or why it is saying it is not supposed to equal itself. (referring to the `invalid` part of the test of course)

Comment: Ok nevermind, I got it. The part you mentioned about the subject being outside the `describe` block made me think about it in a different light and I figured out he must be referring to the user from the first describe that was found int he db with proper authentication. Thanks for that!!